# How to estimate LED lifetime?

Tags: led

I need to use several LEDs for a part of a mechanical part.
But now I am faced with this question of "what is he life time", because the part will not be accessible to install new LEDs.

Until now I never thought about it and unlike light bulbs its not something mentioned in products. I'm planning to use LEDs such as this one [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/e3f8/0900766b812d38bc.pdf). Is there any typical estimate for this kind of LEDs about their use times or modes?

Comment: Heat reduces life. Run them cool and they will last a very long time.

Comment: I mean in normal conditions while they pass 15mA or 20mA current.

Comment: As long as they don't heat up significantly, most LEDs will have an essentially indefinite lifespan, or at least something else will fail first. Heat them up too much and they can fail in a few hundred hours. If lifespan is a consideration, make sure they're well cooled and don't run too high a current if you can avoid it.

Comment: Life-Time estimates are used for many things, but are commonly not applied to LEDs ... for very good reason - they just stay alive until you do something stupid with them. As @Mattman944 said: Keep em cool. See the Datasheet Page 7 Fig.2 : Run them at 20mA (Maybe 15mA will be enough) or adjust according to Fig. 5 when faced with high ambient temperaturs (Keep effects like e.g. the sun heating up a black plastic part in the open in mind). I personally would be more concerned about the lifetime of the pre-resistor tbh.

Comment: What do you mean by LED life time? Do you mean how long until it breaks completely or how long until light output is useless? Please note that the LED datasheet you link to does point to an application note describing the reliability of LEDs.

Comment: Consider using multiple LEDs with individual current limiting, *in parallel*, redundantly.  
Going to extremes, pick different manufacturers to avoid one bad batch spoiling this scheme.

Comment: Can you build in the replacement? So once the LED fails, there is another already there ready to go.

Answer (score 10):

Operated within ratings, the LEDs are unlikely to fail catastrophically i.e. stop emitting altogether.

However, due to degradation of the crystalline structure, and possible delamination between the die and the optical encapsulation, the emitted light level may degrade over time by between 50% and 80%. Timeframe for degradation may range from 10,000 to 50,000 hours.

All this is highly application dependent, conditional on environmental conditions: temp, humidity etc.

You need to establish the consequences of such an intensity loss, and build sufficient margin in to the design to compensate. If they are just indicators - unlikely to be a problem. If they form part of a photo-interrupter position sensor you need margin.

Source: personal experience of reliability characterisation of LEDs in automotive mechatronic applications.

Comment: Do you have an idea how that degradation timeframe is influenced by temperature? Would e.g. a -40°C to 105°C spec'd mid power LED color-targeted to 85°C have a significantly increased lifespan before degradation if underdriven to never exceed, say, 70°C?

Comment: @Sixtyfive The rule is that the lower the temperature, the longer the lifespan and output stability. But I imagine that repeated temperature change from sub zero to +70°C will also decrease reliability. Think of an outdoor LED turning on and off many times in winter.

Comment: Yes, that much is clear and goes for most everything. I was thinking of indoor lighting where it's not quite as extreme. Was mostly hoping for perhaps some hard data from @elchambro, since they mentioned to be doing the characterisation profesionally.

Comment: Temperature cycling causes stress between die and encapsulation, and intensity degradation is heavily dependent on the Delta-T (min - max temperature variation) [Google Coffin-Manson relationship]. Intensity also degrades just due to thermal effects [Arrhenius relationship]. Note that it's the junction temperature that matters here, which can be substantially higher than ambient. If you keep Delta-T to 40C and Tj to 70C, then you should be in a good position. The warnings in my answer still apply re: consequences and margin.

Answer (score 8):

If you read your LED data sheet correctly you'll see that it contains this: -

[image]

And, if you search the Cree site you'll find [this document](https://downloads.cree-led.com/files/da/h/HB-LED-Lamp-Reliability-Test-Standard.pdf): -

[image]

And, if you read that document they give you a life-test figure of so many hours for so many unit. Typically they test 50 units for 1000 hours and report zero failures: -

[image]

**That's an MTTF (mean time to fail) of 50,000 hours (or 5.7 years).**

Of course, if you run at significantly lower current levels you will probably get double the life span so maybe look up [MIL HDBK 217F](https://www.quanterion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/MIL-HDBK-217F.pdf) and see what it says that you might expect for an increase in life for LEDs when run at different currents.

Answer (score 7):

Conventional wisdom (as well as my belief some years ago) is that running LEDs at low current (say less than 10mA for a 5mm LED) will result in essentially unlimited life (perhaps >50,000 or 100,000 hours) and end of life would be as a result of gently fading light output.

My actual experience is that, while hot and overdriven LEDs can most certainly be unreliable (eg. cheap flashlights with no regulation), many inexpensive (and some not so inexpensive) LEDs fail completely (not just fade in brightness) after a period of a few months or years even at reduced current and office temperatures. The overdriven ones may fail in such a way as they pulse or flash, the other failures tend to be just going dark.

I have a not inexpensive office decoration 'tree' that has many hundreds of white LEDs, and I reduced the current deliberately from the very start to extend the lifetime. Perhaps 10-15%  of them have failed completely after maybe 5-10,000 hours of operation. A small Christmas decoration with about 50 LEDs has one failure, with perhaps 100 hours total operation. A Japanese made JVC stereo has lost the LED backlight for the small LCD display (it's a couple 5mm LEDs). I've see failures of HP dot matrix LED display (albeit rather old ones).

On the other hand, I've had quite good luck with Philips LED light bulbs for home and office illumination.

So I would definitely say that one of the major factors in life span is the quality of manufacture. I don't think you can say for sure that sticking to (say) top-tier Japanese brands and Osram is going to result in long life, but buying the cheapest ones that you can find and running them hard is taking more of a chance.

Not very quantitative, sorry. You can find quantitative life data for LEDs designed for illumination, but I have not seen much for indicator and similar LEDs. And I would be suspicious of life data for LEDs intended to be run hard that does not include cycling at a realistic rate for the application. Thermal cycling as well as just running hot is a possible cause of failures. Last time I looked, there were quite a few scientific papers on LED reliability issues, but not much filters down to the datasheets.

Comment: Did you test the LEDs which failed? Maybe it’s only the solder joints. Would also be interesting to know if they were always operated within spec or if there were voltage/current/temperature spikes at some point.

Comment: @Michael Not solder joints. Could be the wire bonds. Could be a result of some volatile chemicals such as solvents or adhesives used in manufacturing- there are known compatibility issues, and epoxy packages are not hermetic.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any reliability calculations for LEDs, only plain diodes.

For any component, there is no guarantee, only probabilities. Reliability engineers use *failures per million hours* or sometimes *FITs* (Failure in Time, a billion hours). These can be converted to *MTBF*, mean time between failures. For tiny failure rates the MTBF is the reciprocal of the failure rate.

I guessed at some of the adjustment factors.

[image]

https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/quality/discrete/diode/common/diodehinsitu.pdf

Edit: these are only failure rates, and do not include wear-out or aging. Two common issues are contamination and electromigration. Plastic is not hermetic, so if cost is no object, buy a hermetic LED at an astronomical price (1N6092). For electromigration, run at the lowest current to meet your needs. Modern LEDs are plenty bright at 1 mA. \Edit.

Why don't household LED bulbs last anywhere near this long? They run very hot. There are multiple LEDs and other components. Economics: If they last 10-20 years with intermittent use, customers will be satisfied.

Comment: MTBF is neither lifetime nor (should be the same with a single non-repairable component) MTTF/MTFF , but "level of the middle part/bottom" of the [bathtub curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve). It may include DOA/"infant mortality". It excludes the region of significant wear/age related failures.

Comment: @greybeard - thanks for reminding me of the wear out factor. When I was working, I would walk down the hallway and ask the Reliability Engineer, that is all he did.